# How do I get a list of all components on a Form in a Python FMX GUI App

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey

I have a [DelphiFMX GUI App](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) with a couple of components created on a `Form`:

```
self.imgDirt = Image(self)
self.btnLoad = Button(self)
self.btnSave = Button(self)
self.memDirt = Memo(self)
self.lblTitle = Label(self)
self.edtTitle = Edit(self)
```

How can I get a list of all the components on the Form assuming I didn't know which ones were on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `for-loop` through all of the `Components` on the `Form`:

```
for component in self.Components:
    print(component.ClassName)
```

You can also do:

```
   for i in range(0, self.ComponentCount):
        print(self.Components[i].ClassName)
```

Both code examples would print out:

```
TImage
TButton
TButton
TMemo
TLabel
TEdit
```